# Will I have trouble getting a B1/B2 visa after overstaying my ESTA by 1 day?

Tags: usa, esta, b1-b2-visas, overstaying

So, I overstayed by chance 1 day on ESTA in 2014.
I traveled back to USA on ESTA in 2015 but at the entrance they informed me of previous overstay which I was unaware. I did not have to pay the 600$ penalty and was allowed in country.I guess I can not travel on ESTA anymore.

Has anybody had similar experience?

I want to go back now on B2 visa for a short visit. Will I have trouble getting it?
My husband is USA citizen but that does not change much I guess.

Comment: Hmm ... it sounds like according to the rules you _should_ have been denied entry in 2015. Does the entrance stamp in your passport from 2015 say that you were "admitted" or "paroled"?

Comment: Before the flight in 2015 I checked my ESTA status and it did not say anything that it is expired or cancelled. Stamp says Admitted. But the class is different from previous stamps as I see now it is said "B2" and the time until valid is given six months...and then there is a note added like "I 193 No Fee". So, I was not authorized through ESTA but instead given a B2 visa for 1/2 year?

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser: [I-193](https://www.uscis.gov/i-193) is supposedly "for an alien **who is a legal resident of the United States** to reenter the United States without the alien's passport and/or visa".

Comment: @jkdze the stamp in your passport is not a visa.  It means that you were admitted in B-2 status for one year (presumably this is because you were statutorily ineligible to be admitted under the VWP).  The I-193 notation has to do with waiving the requirement to have a visa.  They obviously decided that you were trustworthy and that they weren't going to keep you out because of your overstay.  So your chances for getting a visa are probably pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody knows if you may or may not have trouble for overstaying your ESTA by one day when going for a visa. According to the law strictly, you cannot use ESTA again.

From you discussion in the chat, apparently you were given a gratis/fee-free visa at the airport to enter via a I-193.That is very unusual since you imply you are not a legal resident of the USA and [I-193's](https://www.uscis.gov/i-193) are:

> For an alien who is a legal resident of the United States to reenter
>   the United States without the alien's passport and/or visa.

Overstaying for one day does not attract a ban per [INA § 212(a)(9)(B)](https://www.uscis.gov/ilink/docView/AFM/HTML/AFM/0-0-0-1/0-0-0-17138/0-0-0-18383.html) and/or make you inadmissible.

> Under section 212(a)(9)(B) of the Act, an alien is inadmissible if the
>   alien has accrued a specified period of unlawful presence, leaves the
>   United States after accruing the unlawful presence, and then seeks
>   admission during the period specified in (either 3 years or 10 years
>   after the departure, depending on the section 212(a)(9)(B)(i) duration
>   of the accrued unlawful presence).

Is it a black mark against you? You bet! The consular officer may choose to ignore it or use it to deny you a visa at his discretion.

Typically your husband being a US citizen makes it less likely you will get a non-immigrant visa, unless you demonstrate you guys together live outside the USA and you have no [immigrant intent](http://www.americanlaw.com/dintent.html). It does appear you have an **unusual** case/profile and have previously overcome that challenge/disqualifier. Go ahead and apply for the B2 visa and update your question with the result.

Comment: Since this showed up as active I'll just note that the caption for the I-193 form is misleading; it is a waiver application for both immigrants and non-immigrants. If you look at the form itself, the 212(d)(4) reference is the one applicable to non-immigrants and the line below that asks for the non-immigrant class the applicant is admitted as. Note that 212(d)(4) only applies in "unforseen" circumstances so the OP will definitely need a visa next time.